# Ternary operator and Sequence Points in C

Tags: c, ternary, sequence-points, synchronization

I've an expression of the form shown below :-

```
while (count)
{
...
...

    index = ((count == 20)? 0 : index++);
...
...
}
```

Now Ternary operators are sequence points in C but I believe that the sequence point ends at the test part.

Is this understanding correct and as such will this statement lead to undefined behaviour ?

Comment: I think you mean sequence points..

Comment: Why did you even write that code rather than: `index = (count == 20) ? 0 : index+1;`

Comment: @David : Well I didn't. One of my friends came up with this code fragment and we couldn't quite agree on it. So I thought I'd rather put it to the experts :)

Answer (score 12):

Right. There's a sequence point after the evaluation of the condition, but the next sequence point is the semicolon terminating the statement. So whenever `count != 20`, you have the undefined behaviour

```
index = index++;
```

since `index` is modified twice without intervening sequence point.

Comment: And the opposite: `index = (index++ == 20) ? 0 : something;` is well-defined behavior (although poor programming practice).